# The usage of sed c\ command under AIX

Tags: sed, aix

According to AIX man page

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/sed.htm

They gave the definition of c\ command here

```
(2)c\    
Text
```

> Deletes the pattern space. With 0 or 1 address or at the end of a 2-    address range, places the Text variable in output and then starts the next cycle.

I am confused with the idea of 0 or 1 address according to explanation above. Anyone can give an example of the usage of **c\** command?

Thanks

Comment: It's roughly the same as `s/^.*$/Text/` except that `Text` can be multi-line, with the appropriate line continuations.

Answer (score 1):

`c` command will change the line to current position (so often the current line but maybe this is modified using buffer capacity like loading several line with `n`)

the 0,1 or 2 address range mean that you can use an addressing range (line number, pattern matching) before the instruction like:

```
# no address, so current line
c \
Add this line

# 1 adress, so line number corrsponding or pattern line matchin
2 c\
at line 2
/This/ c\
at each line that contain "This"

# 2 address
1,3 c\
for line 1 to 3 only
/Trig/,$ c\
From first line that contain "Trig" until the end
```